# Grafana graph title from Prometheus snmp_exporter metrics

Tags: snmp, grafana, prometheus, exporter

I want to graph interfaces usage from HP switch using snmp_exporter. As an index I use ifName. snmp.yml generator and scraping to Prometheus from switch works ok. Grafana shows graphs with a title taken from ifName.

But ifName is like Ethernet1/0/1 and so on. I have another metrics: ifAlias which I can configure on a switch with 'description' command e.g. 'UPLINK'.

So what I want to achieve, is to put ifAlias as a graph title next to ifName. I can not use ifAlias as an index, because it is not unique (most of ifAlias is empty like ifAlias="").

Is it possible to do something like that? If yes, then how? :-)

What I tried, it to use group_left and combine two metrics. It works, but I can only put ifAlias into Legend field like {{ifAlias}}.

Thanks in advance.

V.

```
ifAlias{ifAlias="",ifName="Ethernet1/0/1",instance="access",job="3com_snmp_exporter"}
ifAlias{ifAlias="UPLINK",ifName="GigabitEthernet1/0/25",instance="access",job="3com_snmp_exporter"}
ifName{ifName="Ethernet1/0/1",instance="access",job="3com_snmp_exporter"}
ifName{ifName="GigabitEthernet1/0/25",instance="access",job="3com_snmp_exporter"}
```